# C++ Nested for loops incorrect output

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to make a program that receives from the user 4 student names and 3 test scores for each student. I have a problem when it comes to displaying every name with its 3 test scores. 
For example if I have John, Bob, Michael, and Mary, all 4 student display along with Mary's 3 test scores.

Here is the function that I have for getting the data from the user:

```
void Student::getName()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter name: ";
        cin >> name[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter grade: ";
            cin >> testScores[j];
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the function that I have for displaying the data:

```
void Student::setName()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            cout << "\nName: " << name[i] << endl;
            for (int j =0; j <3; j++)
            {
                cout << "Grade: " << testScores[j] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

The first function works fine but I have problem with the output of the second function. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: You're overwriting the same 3 scores each time through the inner loop. You don't have separate scores for each student.

Comment: because yu r overiding the testscores[j]  each time. This has the last entered values.

Comment: Your testScores only conatins the last updated grade.You can create an structure which have name and testScore[3].

Comment: Why does your `Student` class have an array of names? You should have one `Student` object for each student. It should just have one `name` member, and an array of scores for that student.

Comment: Your function names are backwards. Usually `setXXX` is for giving values to something, and `getXXX` is for retrieving the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `testScores` a 2D array instead of a single dimension array otherwise you will overwrite student 1's grades with those of student 2 which in turn will be overwritten by those of student 3 and so on leaving you with just the grades of student 4.

`int testScores[4][3];`

Then

replace

`cin >> testScores[j];`

with

`cin >> testScores[i][j];`

in the first function.

And

replace

`cout << "Grade: " << testScores[j] << endl;`

with

`cout << "Grade: " << testScores[i][j] << endl;`

Comment: You are absolutely right, it works now. Thank you so much!